# Hazelcast I/O threads usage

Tags: hazelcast

What is the role of I/O threads in hazelcast? Also how does changing their numbers affects the system?

Following is the link for hazelcast I/O threading model. I am wondering what connections does it talk about?

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Performance/Threading_Model/I:O_Threading.html

Answer (score 1):

IO = Input Output

IO Threads = threads that perform Input/Output operations.

Role of I/O Threads -
(reading straight from the documentation)

3 uses:

I/O thread for the accept requests.

I/O threads to read data from other members/clients.

I/O threads to write data to other members/clients

Connections = connections from other members/clients